# How can I execute two or more JavaScript's functions simultaneously?

Tags: javascript

My question is simple and clear as the title says:

How can I execute two or more JavaScript's functions at the same time like multi threading programming?

I'm asking the question to decrease page loading time in my website.

In my JavaScript code, it makes two requests in succession, but they have nothing to do with each other. Therefore, I want to execute them simultaneously.

Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: like this you mean? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: Hi Dali, I thought you are dead! I visited your exhibition and it was great XD. The requests are AJAX requests.

Comment: Hi Xotic750, I guess Web Worker is one of candidates. Let me check...

Comment: You're right. Those are ajax calls. It's not blocked operations. Therefore using Web Worker are not helpful.In my case, the second request is always about 500ms late. However, I guess that this is because of the distance of servers.

Answer (score 5):

Look into [JavaScript Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers).  They are the JavaScript way of doing multithreading.

Note that a web worker can't access the DOM of your page, but it can pass messages back to script in the page once it's finished its work.

Comment: *"They are the JavaScript way of doing multithreading"* In the **browser**, yes. JavaScript is not just a browser language.

Comment: Yes, I determined to use it. It looks like all modern browsers support according to this website: http://caniuse.com/#search=worker